# (Branch cut of z^2) Can someone explain this picture?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, branch-cuts, branch-points

I am trying to understand exactly what is going on in the picture below:

[image: Riemann surface of z^2]

From what I understand so far, these are two complex planes. The left one is z, and the right one is the image of z under $f(z) = z^2$. I understand that the shaded right half of the z plane maps to all of the w plane, save the real line $(-∞, 0]$. (Please ignore the +/- in the inverse function, I realize there is only supposed to be a '+' there.)

Here are my questions/requests for clarification:

(1) Does the orange circle represents one branch, and the dotted circle represents another branch? Does the direction (clockwise/counterclockwise) matter?

(2) What to the +s and -s signify on the graphs?

(3)Are there infinitely many branches that are sort of 'paired up' by the positive part of the z plane mapping to all of the w plane, and the whole left half of the z plane mapping to the whole w plane?

(4) How would I go about finding these 'branch points' on my own? Would it just be intuition? I don't particularly understand how to do that. It is clear that f(i) = f(-i), but how would I know that these are the branching points, or is that when I know there is a branching point (when two values map to the same point)?

Any extra tips for these kinds of problems is much appreciated! Thank you all.

Comment: There are only two local branches of the square root but infinitely many ways to put the branch cut.

Comment: (2): The +/- represent the positive and negative imaginary axis and where they map to, to show how the map $z \mapsto z^2$ stretches the right half plane into $\mathbb C$. (1): The orange lines represent the two branches we have created with our choice of cut, and are shown "glued" together in such a way that the orange line forms a continuous path (this is, in my opinion, best thought of in terms of Riemann Surfaces). (3): The choice of splitting up the right vs. left half plane is implicitly making a choice on the branch cut, since it forces it to be on the negative real line...

Comment: ... and because $z^2$ is an integer power of $z$ we only get finitely many unique sheets (two of them here) for any choice of branch cut. (4): You are using the term "branch point" incorrectly. There is a lot of general theory if you pick up a book on Riemann Surfaces, but here the basic idea is that $z^2 = e^{2 \log z}$ and $\log(z)$ has branch points at $0$ and $\infty$ so we get those branch points here. Think about what $z^2$ does geometrically: it doubles angles (up to scaling), so we pass through all angles twice as we go around the plane so we need to restrict ourselves to a single...

Comment: ... choice of angle to get something workable. You could do this in the classical way where 360 degrees = 0 degrees, or you could use the negative real line, or you could use any path at all from the origin to $\infty$ (in the sense of the Riemann Sphere). Perhaps think of it this way: no matter which path you choose, on each circle of fixed radius we only get once choice of angle at each point (though the point the angle is discontinuous will in general depend on the circle) so angles will be well defined.

Comment: So in your last comment, you are saying that I pick where I would like the branch cut to be?

Comment: @sfdisk That is correct. Here you have chosen the negative real line by splitting the plane along the imaginary axis (which $z^2$ maps to the negative real line)